# How to run/configure a microservice on a different IP than localhost in JHipster

Tags: jhipster

Currently all applications: registry, gateway, microservices are configured to run on different ports of localhost.
I couldn't yet find where to re-configure one of my microservice endpoint so that I can run that specific microservice on a different IP/machine in my network or public IP for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, JHipster apps (like any Spring Boot apps) bind on `0.0.0.0` IP address which means you can call them on any IP where they run.

This is what your app logs at startup.

If this does not work, you can configure a specific IP address using `server.address` property. See [Spring Boot docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.developing-web-applications.embedded-container.customizing)

Comment: Thanks Gaël, but then how other apps will know the changed IP of this app. For example if I run a microservice on different IP, then how gateway/registry will start connecting with it on this IP?

Comment: They know it from the service registry. Each app registers its IP/port to the registry using a service name,  then other apps fetch the service list from the registry and they connect to the URL(s) that match the service name they want to connect to. That's the main reason for using a registry